# MVC send data from View to Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am starting to learn asp.net MVC and probably it's a silly question, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a controller that returns data, between which some variables stored in ViewBag. With the variables stored in the ViewBag, I create a table (they store the number of rows and columns).

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.widht = someNumber1;
        ViewBag.height = someNumber2;
        return View(someData);
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int someNuber)
    {
        //calculate the new width and height using someNumber
        ViewBag.widht = newWidth;
        ViewBag.height = newHeight;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

The View has a button, and when the user clicks on it I want to recreate the table with different dimensions.

```
    function OnClick_prev() {
    @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new {id = ViewBag.width+5})
    }
```

The problem I have, is that the body of the JavaScript function throws an error (seen in firebug), not really sure why. The error is SyntaxError: syntax error < a href="/Home/Index/36">Index

Any tips?

Comment: try wrapping your link in `<text></text>` within this function.

Comment: could you show us the JS that you use? can we see the whole HTML of the href? is there a closing </a> ?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? `Html.ActionLink` just renders the `<a>` tag on the page, it doesn't produce any javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your JS like below

```
function OnClick_prev() {
    var loc = '@Url.Action("Index", "Index", new {id = (int)ViewBag.width+5})';
    window.location = loc;
}
```

Comment: This will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: Did you try this? This will redirect to the specific Action, but you generated action link i.e, anchor tag which is wrong. But this works as you asked.

Comment: I haven't tried, but the problem is still the same, `ViewBag.width+5` will not compile.

Comment: Try first and then report the review. It works for me.

Comment: Did you get the result

Comment: well it's surprising to me that it works because the above is certainly not valid C# code. Regardless, the OP want's a generated link i.e. `<a href="..." />` therefore your solution of just going straight to redirecting is not what they are looking for. The fact that it "works for you" is irrelevant, it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Both of your solutions work, thanks a lot! But now I get another error, stating that Index/Index/36 can not be found. Perhaps I didn't exactly mentioned what I want. I want to be redirected to the same page with a new ViewBag value to recreate the table and data in it

Comment: @relysis you need to change `id = (int)ViewBag.width+5` to `someNumber=(int)ViewBag.width+5`

Comment: @relysis looking more at this seems like this *is* the type of solution you are looking for (-1 revoked), my answer addresses the original issue in the question. However, there are multiple problems here - 1. The `Index` action has no `id` parameter, it has `someNumber` - you would need to update your `Html.ActionLink` code to accomodate this. 2. The action is `POST`, however, a redirect will be `GET`, to use `POST` you would need to do this using a form or perform an AJAX request. 3. You are returning a `PartialView`, this means you will need to update the UI *after* the request completes.

Comment: @James yeah, I think you are right. Seems I have to clarify all those things before I can try to fix this problem..

Comment: @relysis my advice? ask a new question because this one has now gone completely off-topic, it started off as a simple "this doesn't compile, why?" to "here is what I am trying to do, how can I do it". You've asked the first, now ask the second (if you need help doing it that is). FWIW I would argue my answer addresses the question, this answer presents a workaround.

Comment: @James thanks, I think I'll ask just in the idea that maybe it will help me clarify things a little faster!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the underlying type of `ViewBag` is [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ExpandoObject` is effectively `Dictionary<string, object>`, therefore `ViewBag.width+5` is the equivalent to

```
object + int
```

which won't compile. You will need to cast your `width` property to `int` before you perform the calculation

```
{ id = ((int)ViewBag.width + 5) }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: just realised my initial answer wouldnt work because you are using POST.

change your GET method to this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    // Do some check on id to see if it has a value then add your old POST code here
    ViewBag.widht = someNumber1;
    ViewBag.height = someNumber2;
    return View(someData);
}
```

MVC has default route of

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

so you dont have to pass an id to the method as its optional

then in your view change your code to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new {id= (int)ViewBag.width+5})
```